# Transform tif file to shapefile to get outer contour of area

Tags: shapefile, geotiff-tiff, contour

I have the following .tif file of an area:

[image]

**I want to make a shapefile out of the contour of the entire area**, like the red line in the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to do this with QGIS?

I've tried different things such as the contours function, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried creating the outline manually?

Comment: @Erik Dear Erik, could you guide me how I can do that in QGIS?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a feature in a shapefile?

Comment: @Erik I guess so. I know I can create a new feature (like a new vector dataset) and manually draw the feature around the area. But it needs to be very precise - exactly the shape of the area. I tried it with the extent function but it draws a rectangle instead of the actualshape. Do you have any suggestions? I'm really a beginner at QGIS.

Comment: The extent of the image returns the four corners of the image, nothing more.

Comment: @Erik that's indeed what I found out. Do you know of a functionality that returns the extent of the image like a polygon, which I can then save/export as shapefile?

Comment: I told you how I'd do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the raster calculator to create an output raster with 1 where the raster equals itself.

Input (nodata shown in light blue):

[image]

Calculator:

[image]

Output (nodata shown in light blue):

[image]

Then polygonize the output raster:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Will this not create a lot of polygons instead of only the outer extent?

Comment: No. Look at the image, just a single polygon there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly.

Comment: Incredible expression, that's the best solution!!!

Answer (score 4):

Use `menu Raster > Conversion > Polygonize`. Merge all the polygons in the output to get one single polygon. If you want a line, use Menu Vector > Geometry tools > Polygons to lines.

[image]