# Mask polygon with raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, extents, differences

I have very large raster, whih is basically merge of smaller rassters :
[image]

I would like to create separate polygons for each "group" of pixels with values, to get something like this (sorry for the quality of drawing, it suppose to be separate polygons):
[image]

I have tried to do this with qgis tool "extract layer extent" , but it did not break the small rasters into polygons, but created large polygon based on the extent:
[image]

As this didn't work, I was looking for solution like "difference" but between polygon and raster, however, I haven't found yet, and as the raster extent is very large it seems to not work.

**I'm looking for other tools/plugins that I can use in order to get separate polygons for the not null grouped pixels.**

Edit: for now I have made not very esthetic workaround,which is to generate small polygon around each part-raster, clip it (to break the big raster to small raster), then vectorize the small raster and then dissolve the pixels-polygons.
However, I'm still looking for better methods to do that ,I'm sure there are.

Comment: Are the purple areas where there werent any smaller raster? Do you have access to the smaller rasters?

Comment: @BERA the purple area is the extent of the raster, the smaller rasters are what I want to get is polygons of the small rasters. There are more small rasters outside of the image I took which makes the extent larger.

Comment: Do you still have access to the original/smaller rasters?

Answer (score 2):

Use the raster calculator to create a new binary raster, with 0 where the values of the original raster are NULL, 1 everywhere else. Then use polygonize to create a polygon layer which will have one polygon for each of your original rasters, and one (or more) for all the NULL values.

Comment: Raster calc expression would be something like: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428556/2856

Comment: this is good option. The problem is that I still need to run calculations on very large area

Comment: Unless you have to do this often on many different rasters, just let your computer do the work. Who cares if it takes a while. It will be faster than waiting for a different answer.